# "ImportError: No module named smtpapi" for SendGrid in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendgrid

I'm trying to setup SendGrid with Google App Engine using python, following the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid

I can successfully use the sample app to send mail:
https://github.com/sendgrid/google-python-sample-app

but this is based on older sendgrid python code, and I'd like to use the latest version:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/tree/master/sendgrid

I tried following the guidance here: [sendgrid google app engine python DistributionNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093361/sendgrid-google-app-engine-python-distributionnotfound)

...manually installing sendgrid and smtpapi, and then copying the folders to my gae directory, and then moving smtpapi to the sendgrid directory...

but got the error:

```
"ImportError: cannot import name Sendgrid"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be a clue in the error message, I think you have referenced **Sendgrid** (with a capital **S**) rather than **sendgrid** (lowercase)?

Comment: nope, this gets imported by `__init__.py` https://github.com/sendgrid/google-python-sample-app/blob/master/sendgrid/sendgrid.py#L13

Comment: Right! I was using the old example code and forgot to change the imports! So, "import sendgrid... sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient" instead of "from sendgrid import Message... m = Message(..."